# how to make foreignkey for different fields django

Tags: python, django

hi i'm trying to make a new foreignkey from different fields using `to_field` but it return `product` values instead `no_invoice`

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_invoice = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

class Model2(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Model1,to_field='no_invoice',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

is there something else i have to add ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `no_invoice` is unique and seems like the serial number of `Model1`, can you just make that the primary key? Like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_invoice = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name #self should be included

class Model2(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Model1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

PS: You can also take a look at using a `OneToOne` relationship instead of Foreign Key if the relationship from Model2 to Model1 is `OneToOne`.

Answer (score 1):

**ForeignKey.to_field**
The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True.

In your case There is nothing to add.

When you try to fetch the foreign key field, It return all related **Model1** objects in a QuerySet

your str method is wrong . you have to fetch it with self. like below

```
     def __str__(self):
                return self.product.name
```

By default this method returns id(primary key) of the model object
As your **str** method is returning product name when you try to print or render the foreign key field the string representation of the Model1 object is returned i.e. Product name.

Instead if you want to get your no_invoice field

you can replace your **str** with

```
    def __str__(self):
              return self.no_invoice
```

or

you have access to the whole object. you can also do it this way in your views.py.

```
m2_object = Model2.objects.all().first()
print(m2_object.invoice.no_invoice) #this will give your no_invoice value
```

ref:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/

Comment: yes , i forget to use self , its just a test code  . i dont want to use it in str method

Comment: when you fetch Model2.invoice field you will get Model1 related object, which has all Model 1 fields. There is no need of using str method